# Java - How can I get old and new size from JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

After I do a resizing at a JPanel, is there any field or method from the ComponentEvent generated that returns the old and new size?

If not, is there a way to get this info?

The panel is resized along with the window, when the user drags and drops the corners.

Comment: What do you try to achive? Seems you just need to use proper [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when the resize happened, there is no way to get the old size. Also, the event doesn't track this information.

The only solution is to save the size in a field after the resize. If `pack()` doesn't trigger the listener to update the value, you may have to fetch it once.

Answer (score 0):

From the `ComponentEvent` you can [get the `Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent%28%29) being resized. From there you can get the size (at least the actual one).

Answer (score -1):

In this example i call the `JPanel` "panel":

```
int oldWidth, oldHeight;
int newWidth, newHeight;

//Before resize
oldWidth = panel.getWidth();
oldHeight = panel.getHeight();

//After resize
newWidth = panel.getWidth();
newHeight = panel.getHeight();
```